# Notification endpoint validation timeout when deployed to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, microsoft-graph-api, aws-api-gateway

When renewing a subscription to a user's mail inbox via Microsoft Graph API, we periodically get the following error from the Microsoft Graph API (a few times a day):

```json
{
    'error': {
        'code': 'ValidationError',
        'message': 'Subscription validation request timed out.',
        'innerError': {...}
    }
}
```

Since the request often times succeeds, it's doesn't look like an issue on our side. There are no issues in our logs and the response time is < 1s all the time.

Instead it seems like sometimes the validation request from Microsoft Graph API doesn't even come through to our endpoint. We use an AWS API Gateway. Is Microsoft Graph API sometimes blocking requests to https://subdomain.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com?

Comment: The above error tells that its related to subscription. Check at your subscription level something changed or not. For troubleshooting, you can try, ngrok or POSTMAN?

Comment: Are you still looking for help here?

Comment: Looks like the issue has been resolved about a week ago - without any changes on our side. Is there a way to contact someone at Microsoft directly if the issue re-appears?

Comment: Yes you can check with Microsoft support once the issue resurfaces at your end; they may help. Also you can post in new thread here as well.

Comment: I will move this to answer. So it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

- The above error tells that its related to subscription. So check at your subscription level something changed or not. For troubleshooting, you can try, ngrok or POSTMAN.
- Looks like the issue been resolved without doing any changes in your side. If there is any issue you can check with Microsoft support.